# Multi Javascript Ajax calls are blocking the UI (Laravel REST)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I'm fetching data (summarizing timeframes) for my dashboard asynchronously by using $.GET(). The script is simple, I'm waiting that the page (fonts, icons..) is completely rendered by using `$(window).load(function () {}`.
Then I'm using a `document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]');` to search the related ids and start a query in a for loop.

```
// some date ranges I'm using for the request
var request = [
    [moment(), moment(), 'today'],
    ( ... )
    [moment().subtract(1, 'year').startOf('year'), moment().subtract(1, 'year').endOf('year'), 'last-year']
 ];

// find all data-id elements
var t = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]');
for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    // extract the id
    var mid = t[i].getAttribute('data-id');
    // iterate the request array
    for (var j = 0; j < request.length; j++) {
        requestData(mid, request[j]);
    }
}

function requestData(id, time) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/v1/data/point/" + id,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            from: time[0].format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            to: time[1].format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            sum: true
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            // find elements by id stuff and replace the innerHTML with the response value (it is just to long to display here, but nothing special).
        }
    });
}
```

**Q**
While the page is doing ~ 5-12 GET requests, the page is completely blocked and I can not load another page by clicking on a link. So whats basically wrong here? Is the behavior maybe also referable to the power of the web server that those 12 GET requests cause heavy load? I've also noticed that if I'm using jquerys $(document).ready function, that the icons are rendered after $.Ajax finishes - this results in squares instead of icons.

Edit: I thought that maybe the mysql calls by the API are blocking the server?

Edit2: async is true by default (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

[image: Chrome profiler]

Comment: Using for instance the Chrome dev tools, you can monitor your network requests, which means you can see if the requests finish fast, or if your browser is indeed waiting for them. It does not look like any of your code would block the UI, but I can't say if your success handler is so heavy, that it'll block.

Comment: Kind of sounds like you're not actually doing **asynchronous** calls at all. Is any code on that page setting the `async` property for AJAX calls to `false`? There's also the possibility that you're doing some really intense stuff in `// do some stuff`, but I can't imagine what that would be.

Comment: In the success handler, I'm searching the element again (by id) and set a value by innerHTML function. This should not be that heavy.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist If he's given the code correctly, ajax() doesn't get a parameter to do it synchronously. My advice: Try a code profiler, like the Profiles tab on Chrome's dev tools; IE11 has a good one too. Find the method where you spend all your time, and then fire whoever wrote it. Or, y'know, just fix it, etc.

Comment: @Katana314 The properties object passed to an individual call to `$.ajax()` isn't the only place to set properties for AJAX calls, though. You can set properties for *all* subsequent AJAX calls using [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), which is why I said to check. I probably should have been clearer on what to check for, though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ugh. I hate state machines. I hate JQuery. I hate small towns. I hate vans...

Answer (score 1):

You can add **async: false** in AJAX call.

```
function requestData(id, time) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/v1/data/point/" + id,
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    data: {
        from: time[0].format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        to: time[1].format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        sum: true
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        // find elements by id stuff and replace the innerHTML with the response value (it is just to long to display here, but nothing special).
    }
});
```

}

And if thats not work then replace it by true.

Comment: async is true by default (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), but I will try the false one.

Comment: Wow, I don't know why but it seems to work!? Will do some further tests now, but this looks good!

Comment: Hmm, no after some further tests with the live database, it still blocks while ajax is running. :(

Comment: You can do 2nd option from this link
http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/javascript/ajax-async-false-freeze-ui/   I have never tried that

Answer (score 0):

Below are my ideas on how you can improve the state:

- Have you tracked the timeline of the page(in Timeline tab in Chrome dev tools)? It will show the peaks and downs of page performance. The reason of the bloacking can be different from Ajax.
- I am sure you know that the browser can only run a limited amount of requests at the same time, no matter if they are sync of async. In your case it's 6. Can you cache the requests so that you don't do the real requests every time?